# Nested Component In React Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have this components

```
type UserInfoProps = UserInfoState.IUserInfoState & typeof UserInfoState.actionCreators

class UserInfo extends React.Component<UserInfoProps, UserInfoState.IUserInfoState>
{
    public componentWillMount()
    {
        this.props.loadUserInfo();
    }

    public render()
    {
        return <div>{this.props.firstname + ' ' + this.props.lastname}</div>
    }
}

export default connect((state: ApplicationState) => state.userInfo, UserInfoState.actionCreators)(UserInfo) as typeof UserInfo;
```

and second component as container

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>
{
    public render()
    {
        return <div><UserInfo /></div>;
    }
}
```

but I getting this error

> TS2324 Property 'firstname' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ...'

what I do wrong here and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `<UserInfo />` component requires a `firstname` to be sent to it. You are leaving the first name out..

UserInfoProps is what would define what the component requires to be sent to it.

try adding a firstname.

`<UserInfo firstname="somebody" />`

From the comments it seems like you want to not require the props right away... to do that you would include a `?` to tell typescript its optional.

```
UserInfoProps  = {
    firstname?: string;
    lastname?: string;
}
```

Comment: but i create the `UserInfo` Component to do its logic with out interfere of container. in this way i have to pass everything from container like `loadUserInfo` function. I do something wrong here?

Comment: what I am saying is in typescript.. you define the props that a component is supposed to get.. if you dont pass those props then the compiler will fail and give you that error message. Either you need to pass the property to the component.. or you need to make those properties optional (with a `?`)

Comment: I know what you say. but `loadUserInfo` is `actionCreators` and cannot by optionnal.

Comment: So change the required property. You are saying that when `UserInfo` is rendered `firstname` is required.. if that component is loading the info.. then dont make that property required

Comment: I know, but I have action name `loadUserInfo` that need to be called and dispatch loaded data and it can not be oprional. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: thats fine.. but loadUserInfo is not the error you are getting.. make firstname optional.